# Gravity Forms is adding multiple recaptcha__en.js for each form on the page. Is there a way to prevent this?

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

On pages with multiple Gravity Forms, the plugin is adding multiple `recaptcha__en.js` calls, one for each form. Is there any way to modify or hook the plugin to prevent this to only make a single call?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple recaptcha's wont work on one page. It is a limitation of reCaptcha.
It seems you need the Really Simple Captcha plugin:
https://legacy.forums.gravityhelp.com/topic/recaptcha-wont-work-on-more-than-one-form